# Can't create a turtle object in Python

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance, python-turtle

I am learning Python and I am trying to create a turtle object from the turtle class. It does not throw any error, but the turtle is not visible on the screen.  What am I doing wrong? I can't figure it out.

**main.py**

```
from turtle import Screen

screen = Screen()

screen.setup(600, 600)

screen.title("Python Turtle Graphics")

screen.tracer(0)

player = Player()
```

==================================

**Player Class:**

```
from turtle import Turtle

STARTING_POSITION = (0, -260)
MOVE_DISTANCE = 10
FINISH_LINE_Y = 280


class Player(Turtle):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.shape("turtle")
    self.penup()
    self.goto(STARTING_POSITION)
    self.setheading(90)
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown, your Player.py file has incorrect indentation:

```
from turtle import Turtle

STARTING_POSITION = (0, -260)
MOVE_DISTANCE = 10
FINISH_LINE_Y = 280

class Player(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("turtle")
        self.penup()
        self.goto(STARTING_POSITION)
        self.setheading(90)
```

Your main.py code is missing an `import` of Player.py; it's missing a call to `update()` to display the turtle as you turned on `tracer()` (which you really shouldn't do, debugging-wise, until your code is further along):

```
from turtle import Screen
from Player import Player

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(600, 600)
screen.title("Python Turtle Graphics")
screen.tracer(0)

player = Player()

screen.update()
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're right but surely both of those would have raised errors...  need more info!  I guess it's just update() that they really need to know!

Comment: @JeffUK, lack of an `update()` isn't a syntax error so doesn't raise an error.  I agree that the missing `import` does, so may have been cut off from OP's snippet.